# Loading native library with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a simple Spring Boot project which loads native libraries. The problem is that I have no idea how to specify the path to the native library when running the application.

I have read tons of posts explaining how to set `java.library.path` but every single one leads to

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /path/to/lib/libconnector.so: libconnector.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The project works if I run these two commands in a sequence from command line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lib
./gradlew bootRun
```

The library is loaded and works. But I am unable to specify the library path in my gradle file. I tried

```
run {
    systemProperty 'java.library.path', file('/path/to/lib')
}

bootRun {
    systemProperty 'java.library.path', file('/path/to/lib')
}
```

and all sorts of variations of this. Also tried adding VM arguments to my IDE etc. but nothing works. Could someone explain what am I doing wrong?

This is how I load the native library (located in `$projectRoot/lib`):

```
static {
        // load connector library
        File lib = new File("lib/" + System.mapLibraryName("connector"));
        System.load(lib.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. I should be passing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as an environment variable instead of `java.library.path` as system property when running the application.

The following Gradle modification solved my issue:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    environment('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', 'lib')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `init` method to auto-set `java.library.path`,
here are some codes:

```
    String path = "/path/to/lib";
    String path = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
    // if os is windows
        path += ";" + classPath.getCanonicalPath();
    // if os is linux
        path += ":" + classPath.getCanonicalPath();
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", path);
```

Note: run this method first.

Answer (score 0):

try to load the lib from your class ( just to test)

NB : i'am not sure but if you need to use so file you must be on a linux OS.

```
public class Test {
       static {
    try {

        System.loadLibrary("yourSohere");
       // or System.load("/path/to/lib.so");
    }
  }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/something_local.jar')
}
```

Comment: This is a native `.so` library, not a java dependency so this approach won't work. I need to be able to load it with JNI. It needs to be in the `java.library.path`