# how to extract a file from spring-boot jar BOOT-INF\lib folder

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I extract `*.zip` file that are  packaged with `spring-boot jar` while starting spring-boot application. The reason I would like them to extract because those dependencies `*.zip` contain environment specific native files (.dll for `window` and .so for `linux`).

I think I can use https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-extract-specific-libraries-when-an-executable-jar-runs

how to set that temp location as `java.libarary.path` or can I configure that path.

Comment: Do your `.dll` and `.so` files have to be in a zip? Any reason they couldn't just be inside a well-known directory under your app? I don't think you can control the temp directory name that `requiresUnpack` chooses, which will make it impossible to set the library path command line ahead of time.

Comment: thanks mike. I am downloading them as dependencies from my company centralized location but I can extract and place them in a folder (maven-dependency-plugin).  should I put them in resource folder ? how do I refer that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two typical solutions to the problem "How do I get environment specific config files?".

Solution 1: 
Use one properties file that includes settings for every environment.
Use an environment specific property suffix.
Here is an example:

```
    dev.port=123456
    ist.port=98745
    prod.prot=90458
```

Based on the environment in which the application is running it would choose one of the
port values.

Solution 2:
Spring-Boot allows you to configure an overrides file for the application properties.
One way to do this is to set the 
"spring.config.location"
value prior to calling the 
`springApplication.run` method.
Here is an example (long string wrapped to fit without scrolling):

```
springApplicationBuilder.properties(
    "spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties," +
    "/local/path/on/deploy/host/config/overrides.properties");
springApplication = springApplicationBuilder.build();

springApplication.run(argumentArray);
```

**Edit:** updated per comment.

Consider doing the following:

1. Store the JNDI file for each host locally on each host.
2. Store the path to the JNDI file (on the host) in a configuration property.
3. Configure the JNDI file path on each machine (either by using an overrides file or by using an Environment variable).

Comment: thanks but I am not sure if i am looking for property file. I am bundling JNI file (inside zip) and wanted to extract them to a location when starting spring-boot application and then set that location as java.libarary.path

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna be impossible to know where that zip gets unpacked to at runtime, which means you can't set `java.library.path` ahead of time.

I would suggest keeping the `.dll` and `.so` files inside your project as-is, without them being packaged inside a zip file. That way you have a constant path you can refer to when setting the library path.

I would avoid placing them directly in the `resources` directory, and instead set aside a separate directory where they can be placed. This is just personal preference; I believe if you put your native files in there it will work, and I believe you would need to set `java.library.path=resources` in this case (haven't tested).

For example, we deploy a spring boot app with native dependencies using Docker, and we simply mount the `.so` files as a Docker volume that is available in the container at `/native`. Then we just set the JVM args to include `-Djava.library.path=/native`.

Note that you may also need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for Linux. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072159/loading-native-library-with-spring-boot) may help.

Comment: thanks but I have a question .... are you packaging /native in the spring-boot-jar file ? or is it a separate directory ? if you are packaging then how are you unpacking that ?

Comment: It's completely separate from the spring boot jar. The native files are in their own gradle project; they get copied to a local file system hierarchy, and then we mount that directory into the container.