# Java can't load library as can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, java-11, loadlibrary

I am writing a java web application which needs to load a native C++ dll via java source code. I have placed the dll called "myCPPlibrary.dll" and all the dependent DLLs at the same directory.
My function `addLibraryPath` ensures to add the path at which DLLs are located to add to java library path.

I was expecting this to work as main dll and dependent DLLs are all located in the same dir.

```
public class Test
{
  public static void addLibraryPath(String pathToAdd) throws Exception
  {
    final Field usrPathsField = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("usr_paths");
    usrPathsField.setAccessible(true);

    //get array of paths
    final String[] paths = (String[])usrPathsField.get(null);

    //check if the path to add is already present
    for(String path : paths) {
      if(path.equals(pathToAdd)) {
        return;
      }
    }

    //add the new path
    final String[] newPaths = Arrays.copyOf(paths, paths.length + 1);
    newPaths[newPaths.length-1] = pathToAdd;
    usrPathsField.set(null, newPaths);
  }

  static
  {
    try {
      
      addLibraryPath("C:\\mydirA\\mydirB\\");
    } catch (Exception aE) {
      aE.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    // DLL name is myCPPlibrary.dll
    System.loadLibrary("myCPPlibrary");
  }
}
```

However , i still get

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.test.wms.server.myfactory: could not be instantiated: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\\mydirA\\mydirB\\\myCPPlibrary.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\\mydirA\\mydirB\\\myCPPlibrary.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2442)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2498)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2659)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Comment: _Can't find dependent libraries_ Did you try [Dependency Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker)? There may be dependent DLLs that you are unaware of. Maybe one of the dependent DLLs has its own dependencies.

Comment: @Abra : Yes using that only. Can't find any path which is not known. Is there any way to find which dependency isn't getting resolved by the Java program. The error message is very vague which just says can't resolve dependency.

Comment: From the stack trace, it appears that you are using [Spring](https://spring.io/). The problem may be due to that framework. I don't use _Spring_ so I can't help there. Maybe add the "spring" tag to your question or try Googling for **java spring loadlibrary**. This was the first result I got: [Loading native library with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072159/loading-native-library-with-spring-boot)